# On hover / click change background color for the same bar on multiple charts - chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have 2 or more chart.js canvas. The purpose is to see quickly the same bar value on multiple charts.
When i put the mouse hover a bar on e the first chart ex "Thu" i want to search and change the background color on different charts on the same page, for ex. if the bar "Thu" exists.

[image: image example]
I managed to change the color on the first chart with onClick, but i do not know how to search on second chart id to change the color of the same bar.

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
  <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>



<script>

  const ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1');

  new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [ "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue" ], 
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      },
       onClick: function( evt, activeElements, chart ) {
                          var elementIndex = activeElements[0].index;
                          var horiz_value = chart.data.labels[elementIndex]; // ex Thu
 
                          var bar_bg_color_current = chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[elementIndex];  // the color 


                         this.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[elementIndex] = "red";
                         this.update();
 
                          console.log( chart.data.labels  );
                          console.log( horiz_value  );

        }, //onclick

    }
  });





  const ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2');

  new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        backgroundColor: [ "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue" ], 
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the second chart to a constant or a variable when your create it.

```
const myChart2 = new Chart('myChart2', { ... }
```

Then you can access it from within the `onClick` handler and perform almost the same operations as you did for the first chart.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart1', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    onClick: function(evt, activeElements, chart) {
      const elementIndex = activeElements[0].index;
      const label = chart.data.labels[elementIndex];
      const bgColor = chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[elementIndex];
      const newBgColor = bgColor === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
      this.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[elementIndex] = newBgColor;
      this.update();      
      
      const iLabelChart2 = myChart2.data.labels.indexOf(label);
      if (iLabelChart2 !== undefined) {
        myChart2.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[iLabelChart2] = newBgColor;
        myChart2.update();
      }
    }
  }
});

const myChart2 = new Chart('myChart2', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
      backgroundColor: ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<div style="width: 400px;">
  <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I added CONST to each chart, it works great on all charts no matter of their position in the html source code or on which chart i click, as long is known the chart id. Thanks.
Do you know how to make it work when i mouse hover on bar instead of click (the charts are used only on desktop, not mobile device)? I used onHover but is flickering and color is reverted randomly at mouse out.

Comment: Hi `Ady`, please post a new question for this new issue together with your current code. Me or someone else should then be able to help.